# Ajax code loading very slow

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, imagemagick

Below is my Ajax code which took 3 minutes 15 seconds to load. What could be the problem?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <Script type="text/javascript">
    function im()
    {
    alert('iam in');
            var Name=document.getElementById("Name").value;
            var pointsize=document.getElementById("pointsize").value;
            var bckclr=document.getElementById("bckclr").value;
            var color=document.getElementById("color").value;
            var bcolor=document.getElementById("bcolor").value;
    var url='Name='+Name+'&pointsize='+pointsize+'&bckclr='+bckclr+'&color='+color+'&bcolor='+bcolor;
    alert("srihost.com/2.php?"+ url);
    alert(url);
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        document.getElementById("Div_Im").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("Div_Im").style.border="2px solid #A5ACB2";
        }

      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","2.php?"+ url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    Enter Name: <input type="text" id="Name" onchange="im()" value="yourname"  name="Name" />
    pointsize: <input type="text" id="pointsize" onchange="im()"
    value="50" name="pointsize" />
    BackGround Color: <input type="text" id="bckclr" value="red"
    onchange="im()" name="bckclr" />
    FontColor: <input type="text" id="color" value="white"
    onchange="im()" name="color" />
    Border Color: <input type="text" id="bcolor" value="blue"
    onchange="im()" name="bcolor" />
    <div id="Div_Im">
    replace me
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and here is my server page code

```
$Name=$_GET["Name"];
$pointsize=$_GET["pointsize"];
$bckclr=$_GET["bckclr"];
$color=$_GET["color"];
$bcolor=$_GET["bcolor"];
$filename = 'im.png';
$font='Times-Roman';

$cmd = " -background $bckclr -pointsize $pointsize -font $font -fill $color ".
                " -strokewidth 1 -stroke $bcolor label:\"$Name\" ";

  exec("convert $cmd $filename");
  echo('<img src="'.$filename.'">');
```

It's basically Image Magick code which works fine by creating an image but when I use Ajax it takes a long time to load.

Comment: One tip. Use jQuery to make AJAX calls instead of manually creating the XMLHttpRequest/ActiveXObject. It will make your code much more readable and concise and it will make the entire AJAX call script a one-liner.

Comment: let me try and get back to u

Comment: **Danger** — You are executing un-escaped user input! This lets anyone who can make an HTTP request to your server execute arbitrary commands! `Name="\`rm -rf *\``!

Comment: Im agreed with @Øyvind Knobloch-Bråthen . If you are including jQuery then use it. It will make your task more easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well two reasons can make place. First you are executing ajax on text box change. Which send ajax request again and again. You should call ajax on only when some button/link/submit clicked so only one ajax call be sent out. Also on php side you using exec and convert function which can be very heavy if first case is also true.

Answer (score 2):

In server-side the execution may be very slow. Run a browser debugger like Firebug that let you watch the network requests. Verify that the issue is the time between when the HTTP request is sent to your server and when the response is received.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you tried the same command yourself and it was faster.

So, make sure whenever you do testing on the command line, to always use the same user "su www-data" for Debian for example.

Then always have a log for debugging, so you can make sure that the parameter are all set.

[EDIT]
What platform do you run on? What version of php? what version of image magik?

You should add a few more details in order to let people help you!